# Make the Application communicate with the current Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

My Android app uses its `Application` class (to be precise its `Application` subclass) to run a thread to retrieve data from a website. Once it does it successfully it is supposed to give this data to the running `Activity` (there are 2 activities in my app). How could I notify the `Activity` about this? How can I tell the current `Activity` that there is new available data that should be retrieved and presented?
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a broadcast system.

You can get the context in the Application class by using `getApplicationContext();`
Then you can send your own custom broadcast:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("your.package.customintent.TEST");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Then you can implement broadcast receiver in your activity's to receive the broadcast.
More info here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

You can set the data that you want to send in the Intent by using putExtra.
But you can also store it in a database and by using the broadcasts you let the activity know that there is new data available

Comment: From their description, it sounds like a local application broadcast would be more appropriate: Intent i = new Intent(TEST_ACTION);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing this data to a content provider (which you should, assuming the data is not that small), you can register a content observer on the content provider. The trigger should be handled by the activity. Look [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/observing-content.html)

Comment: I just read that "You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to share your data with other applications" from Google's documentation on Content Providers.  If I don't need to share my data with another application, does sqlLite have something comparable to the content observer?

Comment: Also application object will be the last one to be destroyed in any application.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad practise since you never know when the Application object gets destroyed. I recommend using a Service instead. Read into it on Android developers!

Comment: Why a service?  Wouldn't it be a little bit overkil to use a service if you only need to get the data while the user is using the app?